# Why doesn't Deja Dup complete the backup?

Tags: deja-dup

`Deja Dup` doesn't complete its backups anymore. When it runs, under "Details" I see it stucking at a certain file each time.

I started it out of a Terminal, and this is the message I see **appearing then again and again**:

```
** (deja-dup:13477): DEBUG: DuplicityInstance.vala:196: Running the following duplicity (13922) command: duplicity 'remove-all-but-n-full' '3' '--force' 'file:///media/backup/back1110' '--gio' '--verbosity=9' '--gpg-options=--no-use-agent' '--archive-dir=/home/jod/.cache/deja-dup' '--log-fd=19'

** (deja-dup:13477): DEBUG: DuplicityInstance.vala:568: duplicity (13922) exited with value 0

** (deja-dup:13477): DEBUG: DuplicityInstance.vala:196: Running the following duplicity (13933) command: duplicity 'collection-status' '--exclude=/media/backup/back1110' '--exclude=/home/jod/Videos/.dvdrip' '--exclude=/home/jod/Kram/isos' '--exclude=/home/jod/Videos/Aufnahmen' '--exclude=/home/jod/.VirtualBox VMs' '--exclude=/home/jod/Videos/OTR' '--exclude=/home/jod/Dropbox' '--exclude=/home/jod/.shotwell/thumbs' '--exclude=/home/jod/.wine' '--exclude=/home/jod/.thumbnails' '--exclude=/home/jod/Musik' '--exclude=/home/jod/.icons' '--exclude=/home/jod/.themes' '--exclude=/home/jod/Ubuntu One' '--exclude=/home/jod/.wuala' '--exclude=/home/jod/WualaDrive' '--exclude=/home/jod/Downloads' '--exclude=/home/jod/.local/share/Trash' '--exclude=/home/jod/.xsession-errors' '--exclude=/home/jod/.thumbnails' '--exclude=/home/jod/.Private' '--exclude=/home/jod/.gvfs' '--exclude=/home/jod/.adobe/Flash_Player/AssetCache' '--exclude=/home/jod/.cache/deja-dup' '--exclude=/home/jod/.cache' '--include=/home/jod' '--exclude=/home/.ecryptfs/jod/.Private' '--exclude=/media/musik' '--exclude=/sys' '--exclude=/proc' '--exclude=/tmp' '--exclude=**' '--gio' 'file:///media/backup/back1110' '--verbosity=9' '--gpg-options=--no-use-agent' '--archive-dir=/home/jod/.cache/deja-dup' '--log-fd=20'

** (deja-dup:13477): DEBUG: DuplicityInstance.vala:568: duplicity (13933) exited with value 0
```

This is the CPU-Graph from `System Load Indicator`, you see the process cycle clearly. Like this, it run the whole night throgh, so there *is* an error.

[image: cpu graph]

In `Deja Dup` it switches between "Cleaning up ..." and "Preparing ...".

Two days ago everything worked fine.

How can I force Deja Dup to complete the backup? Maybe removing a logfile helps?

Comment: That log output looks like it was successful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything worked fine again after **deleting the folder in *.cache/deja-dup***.

```
rm -r ~/.cache/deja-dup/*
```

It is [safe to do this](https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/184246).

Comment: I had the same problem and this worked for me too.

Comment: No, this does not solve anything. I have this problem for years now and Deja Dup still hangs (i.e. even at small PID files like "server.pid"), during every single backup. We write the year 2015 now and it's quite strange that this bug is still around after so many years...